# problems of importing winpython packages

Tags: python, pycharm

I use pycharm to write python program. I have installed `winpython` for scientific computing. As this [package included by winpython](http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/wiki/PackageIndex_27/) shows. It should include `limfit`. However, when I try the following example shown in [winpython example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/winpython/winpython_afterdoc/blob/master/docs/Winpython_checker.ipynb), the `limfit` was not automatically included even I already import `winpython`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Winpython is a Python distribution, not a package** containing other packages.

First, download and install Winpython. Then configure Pycharm to use the Winpython distribution by *File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter* and add a new path with the *python-...* subdirectory in the winpython installation.

Then you have all the packages available, which are listed in on the Winpython-website.